# How I can set the buttons on the center of the scene?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I center my buttons both vertically and horizontally?
I can't get it to work, whatever Pane or Vbox i use.

I want to create something like this : [image: How it should look]

My output right now is this : [image: How it looks]

Here is my stage :

```
 public void start(Stage stage) {
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setLeft(createLeftArea());
         bp.setRight(createRightArea());
         bp.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10 35 50 35;");
         bp.setCenter(createCenterArea());
       var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(bp), 640, 480);
      stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.getIcons().add(new Image("https://mpng.subpng.com/20180404/ebw/kisspng-java-programming-computer-programming-programming-coffee-jar-5ac598db779939.2171835915228991634899.jpg"));
     stage.setTitle("Lists");
     stage.show();
}
```

And here's Where i create the button :

```
public GridPane createCenterArea(){
    Button b1 = new Button("->"); 
    Button b2 = new Button("<-");
        b1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b2.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    TilePane tileButtons = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        tileButtons.setPadding(new Insets(20, 10, 20, 0));
        tileButtons.setHgap(10.0);
        tileButtons.setVgap(4.0);
        tileButtons.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
    GridPane gpbnt = new GridPane();
    gpbnt.add(tileButtons, 2, 0);
return gpbnt;
}
```

Do you have any ideas on what i am doing wrong ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: there is no way around learning the exact behavior of each layout - start by reading the api doc, go on with working through appropriate tutorials, apply what you learned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself ! I used a VBox and the SetAlignment Method.

That's how it looks now :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExtaE.png

Here's the buttons code :

```
private VBox createCenterButtons(){

  Button b1 = new Button();
  Button b2 = new Button();
  b1.setPrefSize(45, 35);
  b2.setPrefSize(45, 35);
  VBox vb = new VBox(b1,b2);
  vb.setSpacing(5.0);
  vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
  vb.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
  return vb;
}
```